# From hive to elasticsearch :

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, hive, cloudera

I'am working with Cloudera CDH5.3 with 1 Namenode (ip:...169) and 3 slaves.

I have ElasticSearch 1.4.4 installed on my master machine (ip:...169).

I have downloaded the ES-Hadoop jar and added it to the path.

With that being said; I now want to load data from Hive to ES.

1) First of all, I created a table via a CSV file under table metastore (with HUE)

2) I defined an external table on top of ES in hive to write and load data in it later:

```
  ADD JAR 
  /usr/elasticsearch-hadoop-2.0.2/dist/elasticsearch-hadoop-hive-2.0.2.jar;

 CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE es_cdr(

 id bigint,

 calling int,

 called int,

 duration int,

 location string,

 date string)

 ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.elasticsearch.hadoop.hive.EsSerDe'

 STORED BY 'org.elasticsearch.hadoop.hive.EsStorageHandler'

 TBLPROPERTIES(

 'es.nodes'='10.44.162.169',


 'es.resource' = 'indexOmar/typeOmar');
```

I've also added manually the serde snapshot jar via paramaters=> add file =>jar

Now, I want to load data from my table in the new ES table :

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE es_cdr 

select NULL, h.appelant, h.called_number, 
h.call_duration, h.location_number, h.date_heure_appel from hive_cdr h;
```

But an error is appearing saying that :

```
Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
```

And this is what's written in the log :

```
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO log.PerfLogger: <PERFLOG method=compile from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO log.PerfLogger: <PERFLOG method=parse from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO parse.ParseDriver: Parsing command: INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE hive_es_cdr_10 
SELECT NULL,h.appelant,h.called_number,h.call_dur,h.loc_number,h.h_appel FROM hive_cdr h limit 2
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO parse.ParseDriver: Parse Completed
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO log.PerfLogger: </PERFLOG method=parse start=1425562594378 end=1425562594381 duration=3 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO log.PerfLogger: <PERFLOG method=semanticAnalyze from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO parse.SemanticAnalyzer: Starting Semantic Analysis
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO parse.SemanticAnalyzer: Completed phase 1 of Semantic Analysis
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO parse.SemanticAnalyzer: Get metadata for source tables
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO parse.SemanticAnalyzer: Get metadata for subqueries
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO parse.SemanticAnalyzer: Get metadata for destination tables
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO parse.SemanticAnalyzer: Completed getting MetaData in Semantic Analysis
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO common.FileUtils: Creating directory if it doesn't exist: hdfs://master:8020/user/hive/warehouse/hive_es_cdr_10/.hive-staging_hive_2015-03-05_14-36-34_378_4527939627221909415-1
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO parse.SemanticAnalyzer: Set stats collection dir : hdfs://master:8020/user/hive/warehouse/hive_es_cdr_10/.hive-staging_hive_2015-03-05_14-36-34_378_4527939627221909415-1/-ext-10000
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO ppd.OpProcFactory: Processing for FS(109)
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO ppd.OpProcFactory: Processing for SEL(108)
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO ppd.OpProcFactory: Processing for LIM(107)
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO ppd.OpProcFactory: Processing for EX(106)
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO ppd.OpProcFactory: Processing for RS(105)
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO ppd.OpProcFactory: Processing for LIM(104)
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO ppd.OpProcFactory: Processing for SEL(103)
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO ppd.OpProcFactory: Processing for TS(102)
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO optimizer.ColumnPrunerProcFactory: RS 105 oldColExprMap: {_col5=Column[_col5], _col4=Column[_col4], _col3=Column[_col3], _col2=Column[_col2], _col1=Column[_col1], _col0=Column[_col0]}
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO optimizer.ColumnPrunerProcFactory: RS 105 newColExprMap: {_col5=Column[_col5], _col4=Column[_col4], _col3=Column[_col3], _col2=Column[_col2], _col1=Column[_col1], _col0=Column[_col0]}
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO log.PerfLogger: <PERFLOG method=partition-retrieving from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.optimizer.ppr.PartitionPruner>
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO log.PerfLogger: </PERFLOG method=partition-retrieving start=1425562594461 end=1425562594461 duration=0 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.optimizer.ppr.PartitionPruner>
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO physical.MetadataOnlyOptimizer: Looking for table scans where optimization is applicable
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO physical.MetadataOnlyOptimizer: Found 0 metadata only table scans
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO parse.SemanticAnalyzer: Completed plan generation
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO ql.Driver: Semantic Analysis Completed
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO log.PerfLogger: </PERFLOG method=semanticAnalyze start=1425562594381 end=1425562594463 duration=82 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO ql.Driver: Returning Hive schema: Schema(fieldSchemas:[FieldSchema(name:_col0, type:bigint, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:_col1, type:int, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:_col2, type:int, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:_col3, type:int, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:_col4, type:string, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:_col5, type:string, comment:null)], properties:null)
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO ql.Driver: EXPLAIN output for queryid hive_20150305143636_528f97d4-b670-40e2-ba80-7d7a7bd441ff : ABSTRACT SYNTAX TREE:

TOK_QUERY
   TOK_FROM
      TOK_TABREF
         TOK_TABNAME
            hive_cdr
         h
   TOK_INSERT
      TOK_DESTINATION
         TOK_TAB
            TOK_TABNAME
               hive_es_cdr_10
      TOK_SELECT
         TOK_SELEXPR
            TOK_NULL
         TOK_SELEXPR
            .
               TOK_TABLE_OR_COL
                  h
               appelant
         TOK_SELEXPR
            .
               TOK_TABLE_OR_COL
                  h
               called_number
         TOK_SELEXPR
            .
               TOK_TABLE_OR_COL
                  h
               call_dur
         TOK_SELEXPR
            .
               TOK_TABLE_OR_COL
                  h
               loc_number
         TOK_SELEXPR
            .
               TOK_TABLE_OR_COL
                  h
               h_appel
      TOK_LIMIT
         2


STAGE DEPENDENCIES:
  Stage-0 is a root stage [MAPRED]

STAGE PLANS:
  Stage: Stage-0
    Map Reduce
      Map Operator Tree:
          TableScan
            alias: h
            GatherStats: false
            Select Operator
              expressions: null (type: string), appelant (type: int), called_number (type: int), call_dur (type: int), loc_number (type: string), h_appel (type: string)
              outputColumnNames: _col0, _col1, _col2, _col3, _col4, _col5
              Limit
                Number of rows: 2
                Reduce Output Operator
                  sort order: 
                  tag: -1
                  value expressions: _col0 (type: void), _col1 (type: int), _col2 (type: int), _col3 (type: int), _col4 (type: string), _col5 (type: string)
      Path -> Alias:
        hdfs://master:8020/user/hive/warehouse/hive_cdr [h]
      Path -> Partition:
        hdfs://master:8020/user/hive/warehouse/hive_cdr 
          Partition
            base file name: hive_cdr
            input format: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
            output format: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
            properties:
              COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE true
              bucket_count -1
              columns traffic_type_id,appelant,called_number,call_dur,loc_number,h_appel
              columns.comments 
              columns.types int:int:int:int:string:string
              field.delim ;
              file.inputformat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
              file.outputformat org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
              location hdfs://master:8020/user/hive/warehouse/hive_cdr
              name default.hive_cdr
              numFiles 1
              numRows 0
              rawDataSize 0
              serialization.ddl struct hive_cdr { i32 traffic_type_id, i32 appelant, i32 called_number, i32 call_dur, string loc_number, string h_appel}
              serialization.format ;
              serialization.lib org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe
              totalSize 56373362
              transient_lastDdlTime 1425459002
            serde: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe

              input format: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
              output format: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
              properties:
                COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE true
                bucket_count -1
                columns traffic_type_id,appelant,called_number,call_dur,loc_number,h_appel
                columns.comments 
                columns.types int:int:int:int:string:string
                field.delim ;
                file.inputformat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
                file.outputformat org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
                location hdfs://master:8020/user/hive/warehouse/hive_cdr
                name default.hive_cdr
                numFiles 1
                numRows 0
                rawDataSize 0
                serialization.ddl struct hive_cdr { i32 traffic_type_id, i32 appelant, i32 called_number, i32 call_dur, string loc_number, string h_appel}
                serialization.format ;
                serialization.lib org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe
                totalSize 56373362
                transient_lastDdlTime 1425459002
              serde: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe
              name: default.hive_cdr
            name: default.hive_cdr
      Truncated Path -> Alias:
        /hive_cdr [h]
      Needs Tagging: false
      Reduce Operator Tree:
        Extract
          Limit
            Number of rows: 2
            Select Operator
              expressions: UDFToLong(_col0) (type: bigint), _col1 (type: int), _col2 (type: int), _col3 (type: int), _col4 (type: string), _col5 (type: string)
              outputColumnNames: _col0, _col1, _col2, _col3, _col4, _col5
              File Output Operator
                compressed: false
                GlobalTableId: 1
                directory: hdfs://master:8020/user/hive/warehouse/hive_es_cdr_10
                NumFilesPerFileSink: 1
                Stats Publishing Key Prefix: hdfs://master:8020/user/hive/warehouse/hive_es_cdr_10/
                table:
                    input format: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.hive.EsHiveInputFormat
                    jobProperties:
                      EXTERNAL TRUE
                      bucket_count -1
                      columns id_traffic,caller,called,call_dur,caller_location,call_date
                      columns.comments 
                      columns.types bigint:int:int:int:string:string
                      es.nodes 10.44.162.169
                      es.port 9200
                      es.resource myindex/mytype
                      file.inputformat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat
                      file.outputformat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileOutputFormat
                      location hdfs://master:8020/user/hive/warehouse/hive_es_cdr_10
                      name default.hive_es_cdr_10
                      serialization.ddl struct hive_es_cdr_10 { i64 id_traffic, i32 caller, i32 called, i32 call_dur, string caller_location, string call_date}
                      serialization.format 1
                      serialization.lib org.elasticsearch.hadoop.hive.EsSerDe
                      storage_handler org.elasticsearch.hadoop.hive.EsStorageHandler
                      transient_lastDdlTime 1425561441
                    output format: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.hive.EsHiveOutputFormat
                    properties:
                      EXTERNAL TRUE
                      bucket_count -1
                      columns id_traffic,caller,called,call_dur,caller_location,call_date
                      columns.comments 
                      columns.types bigint:int:int:int:string:string
                      es.nodes 10.44.162.169
                      es.port 9200
                      es.resource myindex/mytype
                      file.inputformat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat
                      file.outputformat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileOutputFormat
                      location hdfs://master:8020/user/hive/warehouse/hive_es_cdr_10
                      name default.hive_es_cdr_10
                      serialization.ddl struct hive_es_cdr_10 { i64 id_traffic, i32 caller, i32 called, i32 call_dur, string caller_location, string call_date}
                      serialization.format 1
                      serialization.lib org.elasticsearch.hadoop.hive.EsSerDe
                      storage_handler org.elasticsearch.hadoop.hive.EsStorageHandler
                      transient_lastDdlTime 1425561441
                    serde: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.hive.EsSerDe
                    name: default.hive_es_cdr_10
                TotalFiles: 1
                GatherStats: false
                MultiFileSpray: false


15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO log.PerfLogger: </PERFLOG method=compile start=1425562594378 end=1425562594484 duration=106 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO log.PerfLogger: <PERFLOG method=Driver.run from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO log.PerfLogger: <PERFLOG method=TimeToSubmit from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO log.PerfLogger: <PERFLOG method=acquireReadWriteLocks from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO lockmgr.DummyTxnManager: Creating lock manager of type org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.zookeeper.ZooKeeperHiveLockManager
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=master:2181 sessionTimeout=600000 watcher=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.zookeeper.ZooKeeperHiveLockManager$DummyWatcher@70e69669
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO log.PerfLogger: </PERFLOG method=acquireReadWriteLocks start=1425562594502 end=1425562594523 duration=21 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO log.PerfLogger: <PERFLOG method=Driver.execute from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO ql.Driver: Starting command: INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE hive_es_cdr_10 
SELECT NULL,h.appelant,h.called_number,h.call_dur,h.loc_number,h.h_appel FROM hive_cdr h limit 2
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO ql.Driver: Total jobs = 1
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO log.PerfLogger: </PERFLOG method=TimeToSubmit start=1425562594500 end=1425562594526 duration=26 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO log.PerfLogger: <PERFLOG method=runTasks from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO log.PerfLogger: <PERFLOG method=task.MAPRED.Stage-0 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO ql.Driver: Launching Job 1 out of 1
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO exec.Task: Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 1
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO exec.Task: In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO exec.Task:   set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO exec.Task: In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO exec.Task:   set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO exec.Task: In order to set a constant number of reducers:
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO exec.Task:   set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO ql.Context: New scratch dir is hdfs://master:8020/tmp/hive-hive/hive_2015-03-05_14-36-34_378_4527939627221909415-7
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO mr.ExecDriver: Using org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO mr.ExecDriver: adding libjars: file:///tmp/d39b23a8-98d2-4bc3-9008-3eff080dd20c_resources/hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar,file:///usr/elasticsearch-hadoop-2.0.2/dist/elasticsearch-hadoop-hive-2.0.2.jar,file:///opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.1-1.cdh5.3.1.p0.5/lib/hive/lib/hive-hbase-handler-0.13.1-cdh5.3.1.jar,file:///opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.1-1.cdh5.3.1.p0.5/lib/hbase/hbase-server.jar,file:///opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.1-1.cdh5.3.1.p0.5/lib/hbase/lib/htrace-core.jar,file:///opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.1-1.cdh5.3.1.p0.5/lib/hbase/lib/htrace-core-2.04.jar,file:///opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.1-1.cdh5.3.1.p0.5/lib/hbase/hbase-common.jar,file:///opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.1-1.cdh5.3.1.p0.5/lib/hbase/hbase-client.jar,file:///opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.1-1.cdh5.3.1.p0.5/lib/hbase/hbase-protocol.jar,file:///opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.1-1.cdh5.3.1.p0.5/lib/hbase/hbase-hadoop2-compat.jar,file:///opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.1-1.cdh5.3.1.p0.5/lib/hbase/hbase-hadoop-compat.jar
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO exec.Utilities: Processing alias h
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO exec.Utilities: Adding input file hdfs://master:8020/user/hive/warehouse/hive_cdr
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO exec.Utilities: Content Summary not cached for hdfs://master:8020/user/hive/warehouse/hive_cdr
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO ql.Context: New scratch dir is hdfs://master:8020/tmp/hive-hive/hive_2015-03-05_14-36-34_378_4527939627221909415-7
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO log.PerfLogger: <PERFLOG method=serializePlan from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities>
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO exec.Utilities: Serializing MapWork via kryo
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO log.PerfLogger: </PERFLOG method=serializePlan start=1425562594554 end=1425562594638 duration=84 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities>
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO log.PerfLogger: <PERFLOG method=serializePlan from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities>
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO exec.Utilities: Serializing ReduceWork via kryo
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO log.PerfLogger: </PERFLOG method=serializePlan start=1425562594653 end=1425562594708 duration=55 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities>
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at master/10.44.162.169:8032
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at master/10.44.162.169:8032
15/03/05 14:36:34 WARN mr.EsOutputFormat: Speculative execution enabled for reducer - consider disabling it to prevent data corruption
15/03/05 14:36:34 INFO mr.EsOutputFormat: Writing to [myindex/mytype]
15/03/05 14:36:34 WARN mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
15/03/05 14:36:35 INFO log.PerfLogger: <PERFLOG method=getSplits from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat>
15/03/05 14:36:35 INFO io.CombineHiveInputFormat: CombineHiveInputSplit creating pool for hdfs://master:8020/user/hive/warehouse/hive_cdr; using filter path hdfs://master:8020/user/hive/warehouse/hive_cdr
15/03/05 14:36:35 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
15/03/05 14:36:35 INFO input.CombineFileInputFormat: DEBUG: Terminated node allocation with : CompletedNodes: 3, size left: 0
15/03/05 14:36:35 INFO io.CombineHiveInputFormat: number of splits 1
15/03/05 14:36:35 INFO log.PerfLogger: </PERFLOG method=getSplits start=1425562595867 end=1425562595896 duration=29 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat>
15/03/05 14:36:35 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
15/03/05 14:36:36 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1425457357655_0006
15/03/05 14:36:36 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1425457357655_0006
15/03/05 14:36:36 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://master:8088/proxy/application_1425457357655_0006/
15/03/05 14:36:36 INFO exec.Task: Starting Job = job_1425457357655_0006, Tracking URL = http://master:8088/proxy/application_1425457357655_0006/
15/03/05 14:36:36 INFO exec.Task: Kill Command = /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.1-1.cdh5.3.1.p0.5/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1425457357655_0006
15/03/05 14:36:58 INFO exec.Task: Hadoop job information for Stage-0: number of mappers: 0; number of reducers: 0
15/03/05 14:36:58 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$Counter is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskCounter instead
15/03/05 14:36:58 INFO exec.Task: 2015-03-05 14:36:58,687 Stage-0 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
15/03/05 14:36:58 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$Counter is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskCounter instead
15/03/05 14:36:58 ERROR exec.Task: Ended Job = job_1425457357655_0006 with errors
15/03/05 14:36:58 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Killed application application_1425457357655_0006
15/03/05 14:36:58 ERROR ql.Driver: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
15/03/05 14:36:58 INFO log.PerfLogger: </PERFLOG method=Driver.execute start=1425562594523 end=1425562618754 duration=24231 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
15/03/05 14:36:58 INFO ql.Driver: MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
15/03/05 14:36:58 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group FileSystemCounters is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.FileSystemCounter instead
15/03/05 14:36:58 INFO ql.Driver: Stage-Stage-0:  HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
15/03/05 14:36:58 INFO ql.Driver: Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
15/03/05 14:36:58 INFO log.PerfLogger: <PERFLOG method=releaseLocks from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
15/03/05 14:36:58 INFO ZooKeeperHiveLockManager:  about to release lock for default/hive_es_cdr_10
15/03/05 14:36:58 INFO ZooKeeperHiveLockManager:  about to release lock for default/hive_cdr
15/03/05 14:36:58 INFO ZooKeeperHiveLockManager:  about to release lock for default
15/03/05 14:36:58 INFO log.PerfLogger: </PERFLOG method=releaseLocks start=1425562618768 end=1425562618780 duration=12 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
15/03/05 14:36:58 ERROR operation.Operation: Error running hive query: 
org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runInternal(SQLOperation.java:147)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.access$000(SQLOperation.java:69)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$1$1.run(SQLOperation.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1642)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure.doAs(HadoopShimsSecure.java:502)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$1.run(SQLOperation.java:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run
```

Comment: I'm really in need of a guidance ! an answer would be more then welcome

Answer (score 0):

It seems the failure is caused by a type issue. You can use es.mapping property to set types in TBLPROPERTIES